# How to return single record of table from controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am able to return an entire table from controller using following method, where I am able to return the table as queryable:

```
EmployeeEntities db = new EmployeeEntities();

        [Route("GetEmployeeList")]
        public IQueryable<EmployeeTable> GetEmployeeList()
        {
            return db.EmployeeTables.AsQueryable();
        }
```

Here I am trying to return a single record based on the ID. How to return a single record from controller?

```
public void Edit(int Oid)
        {
            using (EmployeeEntities dc = new EmployeeEntities())
            {
                EmployeeTable emp = dc.EmployeeTables.Find(Oid);
            }
        }
```

Here, the record which match with Oid is saved in emp. How to return emp?

Comment: Can you change return type from `void` to `EmployeeTable` and call it from controller action method, by using `return emp`?

Comment: Can you share the code, where you are calling the edit function in the ActionMethod?

Comment: I would suggest you learn basics of the C# language before you proceed to build MVC applications

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
public EmployeeTable Edit(int Oid)
{
     using (EmployeeEntities dc = new EmployeeEntities())
     {
         EmployeeTable emp = dc.EmployeeTables.Find(Oid);
         return emp;
     }         
}
```

Comment: `return` needs to be inside the `using` scope or `emp` needs to be declared outside it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public EmployeeTable Edit(int Oid)
{
     EmployeeTable emp =new EmployeeTable (); // or  EmployeeTable emp =null;

     using (EmployeeEntities dc = new EmployeeEntities())
     {
          emp = dc.EmployeeTables.Find(Oid);
     }
     return emp;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.